# About enhancing the "simple mistake" close reason

Tags: discussion

Lately I've seen a lot of questions where the OP posted either:

- No code, just formulas or a description
- Some code with serious syntax errors
- Some code, with serious syntax errors and resembling other languages
  (matlab, C, ...)
- Some code, no errors, but using mainly iterative constructs

Almost always the questions are finally closed, but in the meantime our community reacts in different ways, sometimes providing an answer, sometimes answering in a comment, linking the user to the ["pitfalls question"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193), etc.

Although most of them deserve closing for being a *"simple mistake easily found in the documentation"*, we all know that using the documentation efficiently (and understanding it) is a problem *per se* for very new users.

I propose linking that closing reason to the introductory material in the ["best practices question"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/193). The only problem with the list, is that the number of resources is overwhelming. So, perhaps, a shorter list covering the very essential "learn how to start with Mathematica in NN hours" could be better.

Opinions?

Comment: IMO, you raise valid points, but as this was not the motivation behind the "simple mistake" close reason, co-opting it for that purpose seems likely to cause more problems than it solves. Although the best solution would be to have more predefined close reasons, since that isn't possible, I think we have to be satisfied by giving our own reason each time, e.g. in these cases we can say that the question is of an unreasonably low quality and needs serious improvement before we will accept it as a contribution to the site. Either that or downvote into oblivion.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I agree. My objective is that when someone posts a "simple mistake" question which is subsequently closed, we react in such a way that if the OP is motivated enough, s/he can get the better guidance to enter the Mma world, notwithstanding how bad the question was.